What kind of crash data is Hogwarts Legacy collecting and sending to Avalanche Software?
Every time my game crashes, then I see a CrashReportClient.exe starting up and having 40Mbps network usage as well as heavy CPU usage.
So I'm assuming it is creating logs and other things from the game crash and then sending it to Avalanche Software.
You can see it has used 2.94GB of data over the last 24 hours:


So I'm wondering what kind of data is it collecting and sending to Avalanche Software? And is there a way for me to check the crash data out somewhere?

Not sure why this was downvoted?

How often does your game crash? Curious how many logs that represents.

@Cadence My game crashes around 1-10 times per hour.

If the game crashes that often, I would look for the cause to begin with.
But the contents in a crash report is outlined here: https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/crash-reporting-in-unreal-engine
Crash dumps can potentially be large and sending them often will ofc use up data.

PS5 asks you to send a little recording, a screenshot of the error e several error logs, wonder if Steam does the same
